# How to fix "[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_error(1584), Lower protocol stack error: 54" in Xcode Project v-10.1

Tags: ios, swift

My application is now set up and I am doing tests to checks if I can produce it. The problem appears after few tests, at the end of the process the app goes to the opening page and after few minutes, the screen becomes black but the application is not quitted. 
My goal is to allow the app to stay on the opening page for several hours waiting for someone who use it !

Below is what I retrieve from the console :

```
[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_error(1584) [C6.1:2][0x129110df0] Lower protocol stack error: 54

TIC Read Status [6:0x283ef67c0]: 1:54

TIC Read Status [6:0x283ef67c0]: 1:54

[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C17.1:2][0x127e4a9c0] get output frames failed, state 8196

[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C17.1:2][0x127e4a9c0] get output frames failed, state 8196

TIC Read Status [17:0x0]: 1:57
 TIC Read Status [17:0x0]: 1:57
```

Comment: The console messages are probably pretty much irrelevant. What's needed in order to help you is your _code_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those error messages are just network debugging stuff you can safely ignore. On the other hand, the screen going black is just the normal iOS behaviour, and you can turn it off with:

```swift
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

This will prevent the screen from dimming and turning off after inactivity periods. Set the value back to false *as soon as the functionality is not needed anymore*, otherwise your users will get really upset about their battery life.